# Вывести товары на главной странице каталога 1C Битрикс

Tags: php, html, битрикс, 1с

Не могу разобраться, как на главной странице каталога /catalog/ вывести не только список категорий (catalog.section.list), но и общий каталог товаров (товары из всех категорий).
Кто сталкивался с подобным, подскажите)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то в параметрах компонента `bitrix:catalog` нужно указать `SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION => "Y"`